# Error while executing pyinstaller executable file

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

I created an exe file using the below spec file in `--onedir` mode. The folder got created successfully under `dist` folder. I could see the requirements in the onedir folder `ROY`.

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['C:\\Users\\****\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\final.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\****'],
             binaries=[('bg.png', 'bg.png')],
             datas=[('C:\\Users\\****\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\Lib\\site-packages', 'ttkthemes')],
             hiddenimports=['ttkthemes'],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=['scipy'],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='final',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='final')
```

Upon executing the exe file getting the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "final.py", line 1043, in <module>   
File "final.py", line 40, in __init__   
File "site-packages\ttkthemes\themed_tk.py", line 43, in __init__   
File "site-packages\ttkthemes\_widget.py", line 72, in __init__   
File "site-packages\ttkthemes\_widget.py", line 78, in _load_themes
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't read file "themes/pkgIndex.tcl": no such file or directory
```

`pkgIndex.tcl` does exist under `themes` folder. Should I treat `ttkthems` specially in the `spec` file? Should I add any hooks?

Kindly help me resolve this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of importing the entire `site-packges` folder, import only the `ttkthemes` folder. I have updated the `datas` and `binaries`. Using `images` will create a folder named `images` under the main `--onedir` folder (`final`), you can also provide any other name. According to your code, it will create a folder named `bg.png` inside the `final` folder.

The syntax would be `binaries = [(file_name,destination_folder), (file_name,destination_folder)]` you can add as many files as you need.

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['C:\\Users\\****\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\final.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\****'],
             binaries=[('bg.png', 'images')],
             datas=[('C:\\Users\\****\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\ttkthemes', 'ttkthemes')],
             hiddenimports=['ttkthemes'],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=['scipy'],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='final',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='final')
```